# Is the word "vitamin" meaning "any item shippable to space" a creation of Neal Stephenson in Seveneves?

Tags: neal-stephenson, seveneves

As the title states. Stephenson uses (and describes the use of) the word "vitamin" to mean any goods that can be shipped to space. Is that actual space lingo?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe Stephenson may have picked that up from the [RepRap](http://reprap.org/wiki/Main_Page) community in the open source 3D printing world.  "RepRap is about making self-replicating machines."

At the present state, of course, there are many components that can't be reproduced (yet).  The RepRap community calls these [Vitamins](http://reprap.org/wiki/Category:Vitamin).  "In RepRap jargon, a vitamin (also called an *imported part* or *non-printed part*) is anything that you need to make a RepRap, which a RepRap cannot itself make."

This is very similar to the usage in SevenEves.  They're shipping up components that can't be (or can't easily be) produced in orbit.

Comment: This is analogous to an actual vitamin, which is an amino acid that the human body needs but cannot make.

Comment: @Acccumulation Vitamins are not amino acids. From Wikipedia: “The term vitamin does not include the three other groups of essential nutrients: minerals, essential fatty acids, and **essential amino acids**” (my emphasis).